# GridLines at TickPositions

Tags: plotting

How can I force the GridLines to be at the positions of the Tick marks? A simple code, `FrameTicks -> Automatic` and `GridLines -> Automatic` will do it, but not this code. The error must be in the function `myTickList`, but I didn't find it. Moreover, `AspectRatio -> 1` seems not to work...

Result:

[image]

Input-File data.dat:

```
3542228.204 5433969.188
3542221.426 5433999.371
3 1 2 0
40
```

The code of the notebook:

```
inffile = OpenRead["data.dat"];
x1 = Read[inffile, Number]; y1 = Read[inffile, Number];
x2 = Read[inffile, Number]; y2 = Read[inffile, Number];
n1 = Read[inffile, Number]; n2 = Read[inffile, Number]; 
m1 = Read[inffile, Number]; m2 = Read[inffile, Number]; 
diff = Read[inffile, Number];
grad = Pi/2-ArcTan[y2 - y1, x2 - x1];
winkel=grad*180./Pi;
If[winkel < 0.0, winkel = winkel + 360.0];
s1 = ToString["Drehung erfolgt um "]; s2 = ToString[winkel]; 
s3 = ToString[" Grad "]; str = StringJoin[s1, s2, s3];
Style[str, FontSize -> 35, Italic, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]
iend = n1 + n2 + 1;
Do[xkoor[i] = x1 - n2*diff + (i - 1)*diff, {i, 1, iend}]
jend = m1 + m2 + 1;
Do[ ykoor[j] = y1 + m1*diff - (j - 1)*diff, {j, 1, jend+1, 1}]
xvals = Table[xkoor[i], {i, iend}];
yvals = Table[ykoor[j], {j, jend}];
ungedreht = Outer[List, xvals, yvals] // Flatten[#, 1] & ;

myTickList[min_, max_, seg_, shift_?NumericQ, phi_?NumericQ, 
  len_: 0.01] := 
 Table[{i, 
   Rotate[Pane[Style[AccountingForm[i], LineSpacing -> {0, 12}], 
     FrameMargins -> {{shift, 0}, {0, 0}}], phi], {len, 0}}, {i, 
   If[Head[seg] === List, Union[{min, max}, seg], 
    Range[min, max, seg]]}]

r = RotationTransform[grad, {x1, y1}]; gedreht = 
 r[ungedreht];

sortiert = SortBy[gedreht, Last];

labelingfunc[v : {x_, y_, w_}, i_, ___] := 
  Placed[Grid[{{"Pflock ", i}, {"Koordinaten", 
      AccountingForm[{x, y}]}}, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left], 
   Tooltip];
g = BubbleChart[(Append[#, 1] & /@ sortiert), ChartElements -> \!\(\*
Graphics3DBox[SphereBox[{0, 0, 0}],
Boxed->False,
ImageSize->30,
Lighting->"Neutral",
ViewPoint->{0, 
DirectedInfinity[-1], 0}]\), 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, r}, Lighter[Yellow, x]], 
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[Style[#, "Subsection"] & /@ Range[Length@sortiert], Center],
   BubbleSizes -> {0.07, 0.07}, LabelingFunction -> labelingfunc, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  FrameStyle -> {Thick, Thick, Thick, Thick}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dashed, Thick], 
  FrameLabel -> {" Easting [m\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"]\", \"Subsubsection\"]\) ", " Northing [m] ", " ", " ",}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Grid-coordinates", 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 24}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{myTickList[Min[gedreht[[All, 2]]] - 40.0, 
      Max[gedreht[[All, 2]]] + 40., 20, 5, 0], 
     None}, {myTickList[Min[gedreht[[All, 1]]] - 40.0, 
      Max[gedreht[[All, 1]]] + 40., 20, 5, Pi/6], None}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 18}, 
  ImageSize -> {800, 800}
  ]
```

Comment: The option setting `GridLines->Automatic` puts gridlines at major tick positions.

Comment: Don't be too hasty creating new tags. Tags must be maintained: you created tags but left the tag wiki empty. *I know all about it; the tag system of EE.SE is a complete mess :-(*

Comment: of course I know this option and I used it in my code. You can see the result in this picture... It simply doesn't work

Comment: @Harold - "I used it in my code". You don't mention that in your question, there's just a plot. Posting your code would help.

Comment: Hi, my version is 8.0.4.0 on OS X.

Comment: Mine is 8.0.4.0 on OS X and it doesn't run either. I get the same error as Nasser. Try this: Quit mathematica, open a fresh notebook, copy paste the code you have given us and tell us if it runs.

Comment: @R.M. - Seems to be fixed. Runs on version 8 on XP Pro SP3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the `GridLines` by using:

> `GridLines -> {{x1, x2, x3,...}, {y1, y2, y3,...}}`

x1,x2,y1,y2 are just your Ticks coordinates.

Here is an example:

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> {{Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, -.5, .5, 1}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{0, \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {-1, -.5, 0, .5, 1}},
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "Cos(x)"}]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Since Harald post the code, then I post this Edit.What you need to do here is to find out the coordinates of `GridLines`,so I add a method called `myGridList`:

```
myGridList[min_, max_, seg_] := 
  Table[i, {i, 
      If[Head[seg] === List, Union[{min, max}, seg], 
        Range[min, max, seg]]}]
```

Then we can both get Grid_x and Grid_y:

```
gridListX = myGridList[Min[gedreht[[All, 1]]] - 40.0, 
        Max[gedreht[[All, 1]]] + 40., 20];
gridListY = myGridList[Min[gedreht[[All, 2]]] - 40.0, 
        Max[gedreht[[All, 2]]] + 40., 20];
```

At last, you should change `GridLines->Automatic` to :

```
GridLines -> {gridListX, gridListY}
```

You will get this:
[image]

By the way, the `AspectRatio->1` works well, in the picture above, you can see the length of x and y are same. If you change the value to a different one, how about 2, the picture would change:
[image]

Comment: What if `FrameTicks->Automatic` ?

Comment: @Verde If `FrameTicks->Automatic` then `GridLines` also shuold be automatic,maybe my answer was not complete

Comment: Then edit your answer ;)

Comment: @Verde Why do you delete your answer,it is the complement of mine answer.

Comment: Because I thought I found a counter example where `FrameTicks->Automatic, GridLines->Automatic` was not working properly, but I am not able to reproduce it now

Comment: @paradox2: Thanks a lot, your code is the code I was looking for!! But.... hmmm ... are you sure, that AspectRatio works well? I feel that the (blue colored) grids are rectangular and not quadratic, and the points in the plot should represent 40 m by 40 m grids... This is also when I change ImageSize -> {800,800} to ImageSize -> 800

Comment: @Harald Generally, `AspecRatio` means the absolute height divide width for a plot.In this plot, the x axis range from 3.54224*10^6 to 3.54242*10^6, so its absolute lenth is 180(3.54242*10^6-3.54224*10^6), while the lenth of y is 240(5.43415*10^6-5.43391*10^6).If you want the grids to be quadratic, just change `AspectRatio` from 1 to 240/180.

Comment: @Harald I just tried with `AspectRatio->240/180`, unfortunately, it didn't give the right plot. One more line about plotrange shuold be added `PlotRange -> {{3.54224*^6, 3.54242*^6}, {5.43391*^6, 5.43415*^6}}`.If you specify the `PlotRange` first, like `PlotRange->{{x1,x2},{y1,y2}}`, then you can also guarantee the value of `AspectRatio`, which is `AspectRatio->(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`.I wish this can do some help.

Comment: @paradox2: Thanks again for your hint: specifying the PlotRange first and then using the quotient for AspectRatio was perfect for me